# Understanding process of nested for loop with alert result

Tags: javascript, loops, variables, for-loop, alert

The alert result is 13 and I'm not sure what the process was to getting it. I understand what the loop does and what += means, however am not sure on their connection or how the second loop effects the result.

```
var v=1;

for(i=1;i<5;i++)
  for(j=2;j<5;j++)
    v+=1;

alert(v);
```

Comment: The first loop runs four times (i=1,2,3,4), and for each of those loops the second loop runs three times (j=2,3,4).  Therefore, the second loop runs a total of 12 times, so v starts at 1 and is incremented 12 times.

Answer (score 1):

The first loop runs 4 times (form 1 to 4). The second loop runs 3 times (from 2 to 4). So the inner instruction executes 4*3 = 12 times and we have 12 increments (+=1). As the initial value was 1, you'll get (1 + 12) wich is 13.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a very simple issue that you'll see in just about any language.

At the first line of your code, you declare "v", which sets aside a little spot in memory to keep a value.

When you say `v=1`, you save the value "1" in that little spot of memory.

When you say `v+=1` you're saying "get the value from that little spot of memory, add one to it, and put the result into that little spot of memory.

You have two loops, so the inner loop will execute once every time that `i` changes - so you end up with 4*3 (see below...) executions of `v+=1`

And since you *start* with 1, your results calculate (4*3) + 1

How did I get "4*3" executions?  Your inner loop starts with a value of 2 and goes to the value of 5.  5-2 = 3.  That's the three.  The outer loop starts at 1 and ends at 5; 5-1 = 4.

Comment: great explanation! though the OP is not me :p it's Bobby

Comment: Oops ... sorry :)  I must have seen the tag for your edit and thought it was you that made the original post!